# Vector of vectors memory layout

Tags: c++, memory, data-structures, stdvector, stdarray

A `std::vector<T>` has the property of storing its elements continuously in memory. But what about a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`? The elements within an individual `std::vector<T>` are continuous, but are the vectors themselves continuous in memory (that is, the whole data kept in the outer vector would be one memory block)? Would not this imply, that if I resize one of the inner vectors I would have to copy (or move) many objects to preserve continuity?
And what about a `std::array<std::array<T,N>,N>`? Here I would assume memory continuity just as for `T[N][N]`

Comment: A `std::vector` stores a pointer to dynamically allocated memory. So no, a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` will not have everything continuously in memory. It would be impossible for a resize of one of the "inner vectors" to also affect the other vectors, since no information about this "relationship" exists within any of the inner vectors

Comment: @UnholySheep That’s an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `std::vector<T>` internally stores a pointer to dynamically allocated memory. So while the elements of a single `std::vector<T>` will be continuous in memory there is no relationship to any pointers that those elements store themselves.

Therefore a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` will not have the elements of the "inner vectors" stored continuously in relation to each other. It would also be impossible for a resize of one of those "inner vectors" to affect the others, since at the point where the resize happens there is no information about any relationship to other `std::vector<T>` objects.

On the other hand a `std::array` is a (thin) wrapper around a C-style array and uses neither dynamic allocation nor is resizable, so a `std::array<std::array<T,N>,N>` will have the same memory layout as a `T[N][N]` array.

Comment: Just a note but `std::vector<std::array<T,N>>` is also continuous while keeping the first dimension flexible.